# ASP.NET 5 behind nginx

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, dnx

I have a ASP.NET 5 MVC6 application behind a Nginx server that acts as a reverse proxy. Its configuration is :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:5000;
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
 }
```

It was working very well on Linux until the ASP.NET 5 RC1. Since then, and on Windows before that, the requests to MVC 6 controllers would fail: I see the response but the browser continues to load as if the response was not complete (static files are served correctly). A direct request to `http://localhost:5000/api/xxx` responds and closes immediatly.

I tried to add `proxy_buffering off` but it had no effect. I suspect that it is related to the chunked mode but I found nothing online about this.

Comment: Can You share a network trace, it'll help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/341) in rc1.  The current work around is to add the following to your nginx configuration;

```
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

[Fix](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/406) is scheduled for rc2.

Comment: This should be documented much better... finding this took me hours!