# nginx cannot connect to kestrel

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I'm using DNX 4.5.1 with the RC1 update 1 runtime on an Ubuntu Server. My backend application runs over Kestrel, listening on localhost:5004. My front-end is nginx which redirects the requests to the backend. However for some reason nginx is not able to connect to Kestrel:

`2015/12/07 15:31:44 [error] 2263#0: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: ribandelle.lan, request: "GET /api/track/2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5004/api/track/2", host: "ribandelle.lan"`

My application is up and running:

`arnaud@ubuntu:/var/log/nginx$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mono
tcp        0      0 localhost:5004          *:*                     LISTEN      2389/mono

tcp        0      0 localhost:48663         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 2389/mono`

(the second line is my application connecting to the database).

I have tried various options for the server in the project.json file. I tried to have Kestrel listen on `http://*:5004`, `http://localhost:5004` and `http://127.0.0.1:5004`. None seem to work. In my nginx configuration I also have tried different addresses for the backend (localhost and 127.0.0.1) also with no success. This is my nginx configuration for this application:

```
upstream backend  {
        server 127.0.0.1:5004;
}
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=api:10m rate=5r/s;
server {
        listen      80;
        server_name ribandelle.lan;

        location / {
            limit_req zone=api burst=15;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
```

nginx is version 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 15.04. I'm not sure what's wrong and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I should add that if I listen on the actual IP of the server (ie: `http://192.168.33.128:5004`) thus bypassing nginx, then I can access the application just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently I didn't look hard enough before posting the question, because it was already asked there: [ASP.NET 5 behind nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846148/asp-net-5-behind-nginx)

It seems there's a bug in Kestrel and you need to enable Keep-Alive headers in the nginx configuration to make it work.